# AES 256 Encryption and Decryption of audio files in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, amazon-web-services

I have an audio recorder app in which i am storing those recorded files(mp4 audio files) in my external storage directory. Now when a button is clicked, i want to **encrypt** the mp4 files from external storage using **aes 256** and send it to a **web server**. Then i want  to decrypt the file and retrieve it from server to my app.

My question is
1. Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt audio files using AES 256 **in android.**
2. If possible, how to do it.
3. Is there any external library files to do it.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes it is possible. Since an Android app is just JAVA code, one can write a AES Encrypt/Decrypt library which has the functionality of encrypting/decrypting *any* file - not just audio files.

2) You can start here if you want to write your own AES 256 library: [AES by Example](http://www.adamberent.com/documents/AESbyExample.pdf)

3) You can read up on this library: `javax.crypto.Cipher`

Comment: Thank you @adekock11 for providing a complete reference.